# WPF Binding not Updating in DataGrid (with grouping)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I know there's a lot of questions about binding issues. But I haven't found any solution - nor do I have any clue what is wrong in my code.

I have 2 Collections:

```
public ObservableCollection<TicketEntry> AllEntries  {get; set;}

public ObservableCollection<TicketEntry> Entries {get; set;}
```

`Entity` has a property `IsFavourite`:

```
private bool _isFavourite = false;
public bool IsFavourite
{
    get { return _isFavourite; }
    set
    {
        _isFavourite = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged("ImageSource");
}

string ImageSource
{
    get
    {
        if (IsFavourite)
        {
            return "pack://application:,,,/Resources/star_true.png";
        }
        else
        {
            return "pack://application:,,,/Resources/star_false.png";
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Collection" 
                      Source="{Binding Entries, 
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                               Mode=TwoWay, 
                               NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                      xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="IsFavourite" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.LiveGroupingProperties>
            <s:String>IsFavourite</s:String>
        </CollectionViewSource.LiveGroupingProperties>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

---

```
//Handler for Command ((un)set-favourite)
private void HandleInvertFavourite()
    {
        if (IsFavourite)
        {
            IsFavourite = false;
        }
        else
        {
            IsFavourite = true;
        }
        AllTicketsViewModel.Instance.InvokeFavouritesChanged(this);
    }



internal void InvokeFavouritesChanged(TicketEntry ticketEntry)
{
    if(ticketEntry.IsFavourite) // Add
        {
            if(CurrentWeekViewModel.Instance.Entries.Any(x => x.TicketId == ticketEntry.TicketId)) // already exists
            {
                TicketEntry existingentry = CurrentWeekViewModel.Instance.Entries.First(x => x.TicketId == ticketEntry.TicketId);
                CurrentWeekViewModel.Instance.Entries.First(x => x.TicketId == ticketEntry.TicketId).IsFavourite = true;
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentWeekViewModel.Instance.Entries.Add(ticketEntry);
            }
        }
        else // Remove
        {
            if(CurrentWeekViewModel.Instance.Entries.Any(x => x.TicketId == timeTicketEntry.TicketId))
            {
                TicketEntry existingentry = CurrentWeekViewModel.Instance.Entries.First(x => x.TicketId == ticketEntry.TicketId);
                if (existingentry.TimeBookings.Any(x => x.Date > CurrentWeekViewModel.Instance.SelectedWeek.FirstDay &&
                                                        x.Date < CurrentWeekViewModel.Instance.SelectedWeek.LastDay &&
                                                        existingentry.IsFavourite))
                //has time data for actual week => keep but set fav = false
                {

                    existingentry.IsFavourite = false;
                }
                else // completely remove
                {

                    CurrentWeekViewModel.Instance.Entries.Remove(existingentry);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Also the `CurrentWeek`-DataGird has `Grouping` on `IsFavourite` - I expect existing entries to switch group on `IsFavourite_Changed`.

Things I've checked:

- Bindings are correct
- INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented correctly
- Adding new favourites works ( only existing ones are problematic )

**Why isn't the grouping changing when the property changes ?**

Comment: Try to set the IsLiveGroupingRequested property of the CollectionViewSource to true.

Comment: @mm8 you mean grouping right ^^ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `IsLiveGroupingRequested` property of the `CollectionViewSource` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try refresh group

```
ICollectionView groupedList = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);
groupedList.Refresh();
```